# JpaRepository deleteById() Method Not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this api below that deletes student data as per their roll number

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Delete Student By Id")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteStudentById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws RecordNotFoundException {

        service.deleteStudentById(id);

    }



@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Students,Long>{
}
```

the service layer call this method below.

```
 // JPA Repository Method deleteById()
        public void deleteById(Long id) throws RecordNotFoundException {
            Optional<Students> students = studentRepo.findById(id);
            if (students.isPresent()) {
                studentRepo.deleteById(id);
            } else {
                throw new RecordNotFoundException("No employee record exist for given id");
            }
        }
```

if any record is not present in the database then api is working fine else i get exceptions when i try to delete any record that is present

```
  Hibernate: select pens0_.student_roll_no as student_2_2_0_, pens0_.pen_color as pen_colo1_2_0_, pens0_.pen_color as pen_colo1_2_1_, pens0_.student_roll_no as student_2_2_1_ from pens pens0_ where pens0_.student_roll_no=?
2019-12-28 17:22:25.813  WARN 304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
2019-12-28 17:22:25.814 ERROR 304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
2019-12-28 17:22:25.825  INFO 304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [spring.boot.hibernate.crud.model.Students.pens#1]

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [spring.boot.hibernate.crud.model.Students.pens#1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:692) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2277) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:773) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:952) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.convertCacheEntryToEntity(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:886) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.processCachedEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:715) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:692) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:549) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:226) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:127) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:93) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1288) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1276) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2912) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2886) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3521) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3490) [hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:351) [spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.find(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310) [spring-orm-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.find(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:274) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) [spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) [spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) [spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) [spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) [spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) [spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at spring.boot.hibernate.crud.dao.StudentDaoImpl.deleteById(StudentDaoImpl.java:101) ~[classes/:na]
    at spring.boot.hibernate.crud.dao.StudentDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4c4a6a2c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at spring.boot.hibernate.crud.dao.StudentDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e8e6efe5.deleteById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at spring.boot.hibernate.crud.service.StudentServiceLayer.deleteStudentById(StudentServiceLayer.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at spring.boot.hibernate.crud.controller.StudentsApi.deleteStudentById(StudentsApi.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:666) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1717) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.12.Final.jar:5.3.12.Final]
    ... 133 common frames omitted

2019-12-28 17:22:25.829  WARN 304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@b709fd3<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@322835383 wrapping Result set representing update count of 0>
2019-12-28 17:22:25.829  WARN 304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
2019-12-28 17:22:25.831  WARN 304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not initialize a collection: [spring.boot.hibernate.crud.model.Students.pens#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [spring.boot.hibernate.crud.model.Students.pens#1]]
```

MODEL CLASSES

Student Model class

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "list_of_students")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Students implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -163504605143278308L;

    @Column(name = "student_name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_roll_no")
    private Long rollNo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "student", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Pen> pens = new HashSet<Pen>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_courses", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_roll_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "course_id") })
    private Set<Courses> listOfCourses = new HashSet<Courses>();

}
```

Course Model Class

```
@Data // @Data provides Getter Setter and toString
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "list_of_course")
public class Courses implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6054320183294808581L;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "course_name")
    private String courseName;

    @NotNull(message = "Course Id Cannot Be Null Or Empty")
    @Id
    private Integer courseId;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listOfCourses", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Students> students = new HashSet<Students>();

}
```

Pen Model Class

```
 @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Table(name = "pens")
    public class Pen {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "pen_color",unique=true,columnDefinition="VARCHAR(64)")
        private String color;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="student_roll_no")
        private Students student;
    }
```

Comment: `StackOverflowError` => Seems you call the same `deleteStudentbyId` method from inside it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose that is not happening any other analysis?

Comment: According to the error, _it is happening_. You did not provide us the stacktrace, nor the full code or even a [mcve].

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose now am getting some different error, i don't know what is happening. haven't changed anything in the code. posted new error stack trace.

Comment: Please include proper parts of code in your Question. You invoke `service.deleteStudentById(id);` which apparently is source of the problem, but show content of `deleteById` instead.

Comment: could not initalize a collection happens - when - Icorrupt data in data base .Let say one column is mapped with int but value in the data base in string . it only happens when you do not have constrain for DB column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error you're experiencing is pretty easy to figure out and is evident from this log line:

```
2019-12-28 16:22:47.411  WARN 5260 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
```

Your problem originates from a circular reference caused by the Lombok generated `toString()` method. Your `Students` class references `Courses` and vice versa.

You could either remove the `@Data` annotation from your classes or exclude the fields using `@ToString.Exclude`.

Finally for the purposes of your application, which seems to expose a REST API, I do not see the point of using `JpaRepository`. Since you're using Spring you could very well use the `CrudRepository` which offers a `deleteById` thus negating the need to write your own implementation.